# you will have [committed]/[become]

Tags: grammaticality

CONTEXT:

John tells Bill that he wants to kill Bob. Bill replies to John with one of the sentences below.

SENTENCES:

1. If you kill him, you **will have become** a murderer. Don't do that!
2. If you kill him, you **will have committed** murder. Don't do that!

QUESTION:

Do "will have become" and "will have committed" work in the above two sentences? Is the following interpretation of sentences #1 and #2 correct:

1. If you kill him, the effect **will be that you have become** a murderer.
2. If you kill him, the effect **will be that you have committed** murder.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: All correct, though A and B have slightly different connotations.

Answer (score 1):

Both correct.

But if you were talking about which was the better usage, I would recommend using the second one, because it's more generally used and sounds much less weird.

As 'you have become' is in present perfect tense, it's correct too.